# undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x000000056ac200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am currently attempting to deploy my Rails 3.2.17 app to Heroku's cedar-14 stack.

I am receiving an error running `git push heroku master`. Here is the relevant output:

```
remote:        Bundle completed (141.81s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote:        Could not detect rake tasks
remote:        ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
remote:        and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x007f1e3f3dd998>
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/gritter-1.2.0/lib/gritter/railtie.rb:7:in `<class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/gritter-1.2.0/lib/gritter/railtie.rb:3:in `<module:Gritter>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/gritter-1.2.0/lib/gritter/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/gritter-1.2.0/lib/gritter.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/Rakefile:5:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_9c69b395977c833063f1bf84ce228ae8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 58.6MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
remote:        https://alliance-billing-dev.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/alliance-billing-dev.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Running `bundle exec rake -P` provides similar output. I have read several similar posts that relate to the assets method not being found, but all of these posts seem to concern gems that I am not using.

My guess is that there is a compatibility issue with one of my gems and rails. Based on other posts, the gem in question always seems to be the gem preceding rails in the traceback. This would lead me to believe gritter-1.2.0 is the culprit. I do not, however, know how to proceed from there, or if my assumption is even correct.

Here are the contents of my Gemfile, in case that can aid in finding a solution.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.7'
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'rack-timeout'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'date-input-rails'
gem 'default_value_for', git: 'git://github.com/malagoli/default_value_for.git', ref: '3d458733a2'
gem 'fog'
gem 'gritter'
gem 'haml'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'holidays', git: 'git://github.com/braintreeps/holidays.git'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'postgres-copy'
gem 'prawn', '~> 1.0.0rc2'
gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
gem 'rails-asset-jqueryui'
gem 'ransack', git: 'git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'strong_parameters'
gem 'tabs_on_rails', git: 'git://github.com/xn/tabs_on_rails.git'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'taps', :require => false # has an sqlite dependency, which heroku hates\
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'capybara'
  #gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda', :require => false
end

group :test do
  #gem 'capybara-firebug', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the cause was the deletion of my Gemfile.lock. Prior to pushing to Heroku (and running bundle install) I deleted my Gemfile.lock while troubleshooting an installation of a gem (debugger 1.6.8).

The new Gemfile.lock contained numerous differences from the original, which certainly caused the error. Issue was solved by rolling back and using the original Gemfile.lock.